# To prove a set is not a manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, tensor-products

We know the Grassmannian is a manifold. The Grassmannian $Gr(k,V)$ is the collection of the $k$-dimensional subspaces of a vector space $V$. Basically, we take $k$ linearly independent vectors $(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k )$ and form a wedge product $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_k $. Two wedge products differing by a global factor are deemed the same.

Now let us consider instead of the wedge product, the symmetric product, namely,

$$ v_1 \vee v_2 \vee \ldots \vee v_k . $$

We shall still identify two products differing by a global factor. Note that now the $v$'s can be linearly dependent or even all identical.

It is conjectured that **this will not result in a manifold**. But I have no idea how to prove it. The field can be either complex or real.

Comment: In the set you are asking about, do $v_1, \dots, v_k$ have to be linearly independent as in the first case, or are they arbitrary?

Comment: Are you working over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You presumably want to still at least require the $v_i$ to be nonzero (otherwise when you identify products that differ by a scalar factor the whole thing will collapse).

Answer (score -1):

I will first make your question precise.

You begin with the space $(\Bbb R^n \setminus 0)^k$ of $k$-tuples of nonzero vectors. You then quotient by an action of $A \cong (\Bbb R^\times)^k$, where $A$ is the subgroup of $(\Bbb R^\times)^k$ so that the product of all $k$ terms is one.

This simply gives the product of $k$ copies of $\Bbb{RP}^{n-1}$. This is a manifold. The same thing happens over $\Bbb C$.

This is the subset of $(\Bbb R^n)^{\otimes k}$, consisting of simple tensors, quotiented by the remaining overall $\Bbb R^\times$ action.

Comment: you forgot to quotient by the permutations.